# Did Ten and Eleven meet in 1969?

Tags: doctor-who

The tenth and eleventh doctors have both been to 1969: Ten was sent there by the Weeping angels (and went to see the 1969 shuttle launch), and Eleven ended up there when he got involved with the Silence (at the same shuttle launch).

Now, I don't know how likely this is, but when Sally Sparrow sees the Doctor he says:

> Look, sorry, I've got a bit of a complex life. Things don't always happen to me in quite the right order. Gets a bit confusing at times, especially at weddings. *I'm rubbish at weddings, **especially my own.***

Is this a coincidence? Ten at that time hadn't been sent to 1969, but Martha does mention they'd been to 1969 *four times* before getting stuck. And the Eleventh Doctor *does* have a wedding.

Did they meet at all? Is that allowed?

Comment: "shuttle launch?"  I think you mean "manned rocket launch."

Comment: 10 and 11 met in "The Day of The Doctor"...but now I realize this was an old question that popped into the main page, so everything I wrote is useless now, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can only answer your very last question: *is it allowed*.

There have been several cross-Doctor meetings. The old series had The Three Doctors (with 1, 2 and 3), The Five Doctors (with Doctors 1 through 5) and The Two Doctors (with 6 and 2). The new series had Time Crash, a short mini-episode with 5 and 10.

From what I could see (I only watched Time Crash, personally), any meeting between Doctors is usually an accident, some TARDIS-related timey-wimey fluctuations, or some powerful entity summoning the doctors between times. However, in The Next Doctor, Doctor #10 meets a man he believes to be a future incarnation of himself, and doesn't seem to be particularly worried about it.

Comment: Except in the Next Doctor the person claiming to be the "Doctor" was actually just a human.

Comment: "he believes to be", as I said. It's Tennant's reaction that's important, not the fact of Jackson Lake's identity.

Comment: Doctors can cross in real life. Doctor 10 is married to Doctor 5's daughter (Georgina Moffett) who played the title role, Jenny in The Doctor's Daughter.  BTW they have two daughters now. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey This fact is more frequently phrased as "the Doctor's daughter played the Doctor's Daughter, then married the Doctor and had the Doctor's daughters".

Comment: @Darael - MIND = BLOWN.

Comment: How Tennant and Moffett did not name one of their daughters Susan is simply beyond me...

Answer (score 7):

In the Three Doctors, they were actually brought together by the Time Lord command structure, albeit reluctantly as it was a violation of the First Law.  The homeworld of the time lords was under siege by a black hole that was a bridge to another universe and the only way they could see to escape was to bring all three Doctors together to solve the crisis.

I haven't seen any of the other crossovers, but in general, the [First Law of Time Travel](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Laws_of_Time) dictates that a Time Lord must not cross his/her own path in order to meet a previous incarnation of themselves.  So while the Doctor has on occasion met himself, it was usually always either a supreme crisis or an accident that brought them together.

Comment: I wonder if there's an element of "intent" required - that The Doctor "must not seek to cross his own path to meet a previous incarnation", but if he **inadvertently** meets a future incarnation, that's not a problem.

Comment: Doctor Who and James Kirk generally have the same attitude regarding rules.

Answer (score 3):

Earth and 1969 describe a lot of coordinates in space-time.  Plenty of room for multiple incarnations of the Doctor to exist without meeting each other.  Keep in mind two other things.

1. The Doctor does not usually seek to cross his own timeline.  When he does so, it's generally in a very nuanced fashion.
2. The TARDIS itself will both generally act to make sure that it doesn't cross it's own timeline and it instinctively tries to avoid fixed points.  Jack Harkness after being revived by Rose Tyler is essentially a living fixed point in time, which is why the TARDIS jumped nearly to the end of the Universe to try to shake him off it's exterior.

Comment: I don't know that the tardis specifically avoids fixed points. They certainly seem to end up in a few. 1969, Mars, Pompeii...

Answer (score 1):

According to the proses, both the third, fifth, sixth, seventh and eigth doctors were also on earth in 1969.

Three of them, fifth, sixth and seventh were all visiting the Woodstock Music Festival, (to my knowledge, without meeting each other, although i haven´t actually read the story).

Doctors don´t have to meet just because they are in the same area at the same time...